# Can't remember the name of a mussar sefer

Tags: mussar-ethics, chasidut-hasidism, books-generally, derech-eretz-manners

I'm trying to remember the name of a sefer that I learnt with someone a couple of times a while ago. It was written by a chasidic rebbe, but isn't just popular amongst chasidim. We were learning a chapter about the importance of middot. The rebbe wrote other sefarim with the same name that were a commentary on the Torah.

Can anyone think of a sefer that fits this description?

Thanks.

Comment: Meir, Welcome to mi.yodeya, and thanks very much for the interesting question! We'd love to have you as a fully-registered member, which you can accomplish at http://mi.yodeya.com/users/login

Comment: Closing per http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/02/lets-play-the-guessing-game/.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think I can Isolate four authors for you it is either the **Sfas Emes** (but he does not have A chapter on Middos) The Piasetztner **Aish Kodesh** (but he has No Commentary to CHumash with the same name. or Maybe **Rav TZadok Hachoen Milublin** who wrote a lot of Sefarim with Different Names but people Just say Reb Tzaddok.And last but not least **Nesivos Shalom**. I hope you find this  somewhat Helpful.

Comment: I signed up and now the website isn't recognising me as the writer of the question. Anyway, thanks for you answer SimchasTorah, the sefer was indeed the Nesivos Shalom. I now plan on learning it:)